# What is a PHP anonymous function?

Tags: php

What is an anonymous function in PHP? Could you give me a simple example, please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP.net has a manual page about [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and on Wikipedia you can read about [Anonymous functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) in general.

> Anonymous functions can be used to contain functionality that need not be named and possibly for short-term use. Some notable examples include closures.

**Example from PHP.net**

```
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

**PHP 4.0.1 to 5.3**

```
$foo = create_function('$x', 'return $x*$x;');
$bar = create_function("\$x", "return \$x*\$x;");
echo $foo(10);
```

**PHP 5.3**

```
$x = 3;
$func = function($z) { return $z *= 2; };
echo $func($x); // prints 6
```

> PHP 5.3 does support closures but the variables must be explicitly indicated

```
$x = 3;
$func = function() use(&$x) { $x *= 2; };
$func();
echo $x; // prints 6
```

*Examples taken from Wikipedia and php.net*

Comment: Though I write PHP for years now, it did not know that this was possible! Nice.

Comment: PHP doesn't support currying (not natively at least)

Comment: @Nils It's been around since 5.3.0, so it's kind of a new.

Comment: @NullUserException, Quoted the best explenation I found, removing the curry-part. Also `Prior to 4.0.1, PHP had no anonymous function support.`, so it's not very new. Different ( better ) syntax in 5.3 though.

Comment: If we could do something like this, it'd be even more awesome: $x = function($y) { return $y * 2; } ( $z );

Answer (score 1):

The first results from Google gives you the answer:

http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~-([a-z])~', function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
}, 'hello-world');
// outputs helloWorld
```

That you use a function as a parameter (in this example) is an "anonymous function". Anonymous since you don't declare the function explicit like "normally" do it.

```
function foo($match) {
 return strtoupper($match[1]);
}
```